# Search in django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, search

I am trying to have search option i my page. I have tried the method given in the standard django document in this link 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/', but my search function isn't working. only the url changes from `http://localhost:8000/contact` this to `http://localhost:8000/contact/your-contact/?q=harini` but datas are not filtered and displayed. I am using django 1.11. Could anyone help me with it? Thanks in advance

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class ContactModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.BooleanField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import ContactModel
from .forms import ContactForm

class ContactView(CreateView):
    model_class = ContactModel
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact-thanks')
    initial = {'name': 'value'}
    template_name = 'contact/contact.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model = self.model_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'model': ContactForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')

            else:
                form = ContactForm()

                return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})

class ContactlistView(CreateView):
    model = ContactModel
    template_name = 'contact/contactlist.html'

    def search(request):
        query = request.GET['q']
        t = loader.get_template('template/contact/contactlist.html')
        c = Context({ 'query': query,})

        if query:
            results = Contact.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(dob__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(address__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(gender__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(phone_number__icontains=query))

            return render(request, 'contactlist.html', {'form': form})

        else:
            return render(request, 'contactlist.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'contact'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^your-contact/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^your-contact/thanks/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^contact-list/$', views.ContactlistView.as_view(), name='contactlist'),
    url(r'^contact-list/your-contact/$', views.ContactlistView.as_view(), name='contactlist'),
]
```

templates/contact/contactlist.html

```
<form method="get" action="contact-list/">
  <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="q" placeholder="Search" value= "{{ request.GET.q }}">
  {% if contact %}
  {% for each_contact in contacts %}
  <h3>Name: {{ contact.name }}</h3>
  <p>Dob: {{ contact.dob }}</p>
  <p>Gender: {{ contact.gender }}</p>
  <p>Address: {{ contact.address }}</p>
  <p>Phone Number: {{ contact.phone_number}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" >
</form>
```

Comment: Replace `if q:` with `if query:`.

Comment: it doesn't work @Selcuk

Comment: Ok, where do you display your search results in your template?

Comment: I think you should replace def search(request) with def get (self, request) and point your contact-list url to ContactListView

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is pointed to `your-contact/`

```
<form method="get" action="your-contact/">
```

So this URL calls the view `ContactView()`, whereas the *`search` query process* is in the `ContactlistView()` view

```
class ContactlistView(CreateView):
     ''' '''
    def search(request):
        query = request.GET['q']
```

A solution is:
**a little edit in your URLs patterns:**

```
 url(r'^contact-list/$', views.ContactlistView.as_view(), name='contactlist'),
```

And **change the form action url** and point it to this view `ContactlistView():` with `contact-list/`

```
<form method="get" action="contact-list/">
```

> Don't forget to replace `if q:` with `if query:`

Comment: i have made all the changes you said. but just url changes and the filter isn't working still

Comment: can you add the new edit to your post to see where the issue is?

Comment: sure. Just a min

Comment: i have made changes to the code. Could you please check it?

Comment: the url is pointed to `Contactview()` however it should've pointed to `ContactlistView`, I already said that in my answer: `url(r'^contact-list/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contactlist'),` change it to `url(r'^contact-list/$', views.ContactlistView.as_view(), name='contactlist'),` make sure that everything matches, `ContactlistView`

Answer (score 0):

I think the view as you have it right now is doing nothing, you should modify it in:

```
class ContactlistView(CreateView):
    model = ContactModel
    template_name = 'contact/contactlist.html'

    def get(self, request):
        query = request.GET['q']
        t = loader.get_template('template/contact/contactlist.html')
        c = Context({ 'query': query,})

        if query:
            results = Contact.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(dob__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(address__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(gender__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(phone_number__icontains=query))

            return render(request, 'contactlist.html', {'form': form})

        else:
            return render(request, 'contactlist.html', {'form': form})
```

Also please note a couple of things:

- you're inheriting froma CreateView but you are not creating anything and you are not getting any advantage from that view, you should use a GenericView instead
- you're defining the template as class attribute but then you are rendering you are doing everything manually because you are not getting (again) advantage of the CBV